# Django: Accessing user-uploaded files in view

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-media

I have the following question:

I have a listview that lists a number of user uploaded PDF files. I am creating a method that Zips them all in a .zip file and emails them (when a button is clicked).

I have the following question: I am currently working locally on test data, but on our production setup the User Uploaded files are kept on a seperate S3 storage server. (As I understand is common). Since these files are on a different server however, do I need to write code in my view to download them first?

Lets say for example that this is the model of an PDF file

```
class ResumeItemFile(models.Model):
item = models.ForeignKey(ResumeItem, related_name='attachment_files')
file = models.FileField(
    max_length=255, upload_to=RandomizedFilePath('resume_attachments'),
    verbose_name=_('Attachment'))
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Naam'), blank=True)
```

Since the file field links to a different S3 server, would a ResumeItemFile.file call result in a .get request that I need to handle, or does Django do this stuff automatically in the background?

Comment: Yes, You have to download first all file in your server then you can compress all files in zip and serve to client from your server or  you can save that zip file to s3 after compress from server.